# How do I change the TeXShop spellchecker to "automatic"?

Tags: texshop

The TeXShop spellchecker always switches back to the system language, no matter how often I set it to "automatic by language". 
The system preferences are set to automatic and this works fine with the apple text editor, so it must be a TeXShop problem.
I use TeXShop Version 3.77 (3.77) 
with OS 10.11.6.

Comment: If you are using a `% !TEX spellcheck = fr-FR` line (e.g. for French) and it's still not working I would recommend reporting the issue directly to Dick Koch (the author of TeXShop).

Comment: I don't want french or german, then I would have to change it manually for every document.  I want "automatic by language".

Comment: Ok. I can't reproduce this. Typing in French and English seems to give me corrections in the correct language.